# C++ regular expression with regexec() don't match

Tags: c++, c, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression to evaluate a sequence of numbers begining with an underscore like this: _201312
I have problems with the numeric part; I always receive the REG_NOMATCH message.
Here is the code:

```
#include <regex.h>

int result_exp,flag_buffer=0;
regex_t rx_t;
regmatch_t match[10];
result_exp = regcomp(&rx_t,"^[0-9]+$",REG_NOSUB); //
if(result_exp==0){
    printf("result_exp es 0\n");
}else if(result_exp == REG_BADBR){
    printf("REG_BADBR\n");
}else if(result_exp == REG_BADPAT){
    printf("REG_BADPAT\n");
}
result_exp = regexec(&rx_t, tableName.c_str(), 0, 0, 0);
if(result_exp==0){ //match
    flag_buffer=1;  
}else if(result_exp == REG_NOMATCH){
    printf("REG_NOMATCH\n");
}
```

I tried with this expression too:

```
result_exp = regcomp(&rx_t,"[[:digit:]]+",REG_NOSUB);
```

I used the REG_NOSUB flag and then I don't, and the result was the same.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: what about the _ it must be in the regex to right, since you start with a'^'? How about change the regex to "^_[0-9]+$"?

Comment: This look like plain C to me, Why C++ in the title and as a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   regmatch_t m[1];
   regex_t r;

   if ( regcomp( &r,"^_[0-9]+", REG_EXTENDED ) != 0 ) {
        printf("failed create regexp\n");
   }

   regexec( &r, "_2211231", 1, m, 0 );
```