# Is there any way to extract URL from text in C++

Tags: c++, regex

In PHP I can write regex to extract URL from the text.
Wanted to know any such class or method available in C++?

I am working with streaming data, which may contains URLs. I want to extract each URL from that with there count value.

I can use vector or other data structure for later processing but question is with title.

Comment: No, you can't do that with C++, there is simply no way, sorry. Processing strings is beyond the capabilities of the language I am afraid.

Comment: umm...maybe use a regex library?

Comment: Pro tip: C++ has `<regex>`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574895/c-regular-expression-with-regexec-dont-match/20575021#20575021

Comment: you can use C++ <regex>

Comment: Try C++ 11 regex:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
int main()
{
    // repeated search (see also std::regex_iterator)
    std::string log("The link of this question: https://stackoverflow.com:1234/questions/");
    std::regex r("https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{1,256}");
    std::smatch sm;
    while(regex_search(log, sm, r))
    {
        std::cout << sm.str() << '\n';
        log = sm.suffix();
    }
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 introduced `<regex>` as part of the standard library.

Let's take a look at how to use it.

First we need to import the header.

```
#include <regex>
```

Now let's declare our URL regex. For now we'll use something very simple. I'll leave it up to you to replace it with a more complete regex. Notice how we use `\\` instead of just `\` to escape things. `\` itself is a special character in C++ so we need to escape it.

```
std::regex url(".*\\..*");
```

Let's create a string to test this against.

```
std::string url_test = "example.com";
```

Now let's check if `url_test` matches `url` and print out a message accordingly.

```
if(regex_match(url_test, url)) {
  std::cout << "It's a url!" << std::endl;
} else {
  std::cout << "Oh snap! It's not a url!" << std::endl;
}
```

Our complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::regex url(".*\\..*");
  std::string url_test = "example.com";

  if(regex_match(url_test, url)) {
    std::cout << "It's a url!" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Oh snap! It's not a url!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Read more at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote?

Comment: your regex matches anything with a '.' in it -- everything from "." to "I had a very nice day today.  Even though it was raining."

Comment: "For now we'll use something very simple. I'll leave it up to you to replace it with a more complete regex."

It's simply for demonstration, not production use. URL regexes can be easily found online with a single search.

Comment: Example code for regex can easily be found with a search as well - as is - you simply added an example with an ineffective regex to the comments before your post about about using regex. Giving a better regex would make this answer of more value.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to a regex, I use the following to match a multitude of links:

```
\b(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]
   | ((?:mailto:)?[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})\b)
|"(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[^"\r\n]+"?
|'(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[^'\r\n]+'
```

This allows matching of web links with and without http/https at the beginning, email links with and without a mailto at the start, ftp links and file links, as well as links within single or double quotes.

I have not used the regex functionality of C++ (`<regex>` ) however shall have a look at it today and get back to you with some code exemplars.